# flutter column + wrap in web overflow but not in mobile

Tags: flutter

In mobile I got no overflow but when I opened it in web I have overflow. Why? The 'error' is in a Column with a Wrap inside that loads data from a future.
Any idea?

(I can a SingleChildScrollView before the column to fix the problem, but then I have two scrolls and I only want to use the parent scroll)

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you dind‘t share your code, I can‘t help you better then:
You can add to the scrollable Widget where you dont want any scrolling:

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: thanks, i tried but then i can't scroll the parent page

Comment: I see. Can you maybe create an example-code and write it instead of the pictures so I can copy paste it. I will try to solve it on my own machine